# How to disable automatic suspend warning

Tags: 13.10, suspend

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 as htpc. To save some power, i have set it to suspend after 30minutes of inactivity. Before entering suspended state, a popup appears to warn me that computer is about to get put to sleep. This is a little annoyance since it appears when i resume the pc later.

How can i disable this notification for good?

Comment: I'd also like to remove this -- it started happening with 13.10 and seems completely pointless as the notification only appears after the display has turned off (~10 minutes before suspending) and persists after waking up.

Comment: This is fixed in 14.04. The warning shows up as a desktop notification instead of a message box that needs to be cleared.

Comment: I have 22.04 and it is a message box again

Answer (score 2):

One workaround posted on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1232454) is a script that is based on the hooks of pm-utils:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_kill-notify-osd https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1232454/+attachment/3942236/+files/20_kill-notify-osd
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_kill-notify-osd
```

Another workaround might be the following method:

Download a script and make it executable:

```
wget -O ~/.suspendwarning.sh https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1232454/+attachment/3942095/+files/myscripts
chmod +x ~/.suspendwarning.sh
```

Add it to `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo "if [ -f ~/.suspendwarning.sh ]; then
. ~/.suspendwarning.sh
fi" >> ~/.bashrc
```

After logging out and in the notifications should not pop up anymore after resume.